# How to config spatie/laravel-backup when datadase was on another machine

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4

I try to use `spatie/laravel-backup`, In my local I can config `'dump_binary_path' => '/usr/local/mysql/bin'`.

But in my PROD server database was on another machine. My application call database server from `IP`.

How to config `'dump_binary_path'` for PROD server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a filesystem in `config/filesystems.php`, then in the `laravel-backup.php` config you can specify which connection the destination should be.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the mysql-client package on your application server, which gives you access to mysql and mysqldump. These binaries CAN access remote servers (assuming the user that is used to connect with has permission, but that's a MySQL issue, not one related to this package, although it affects this package).

[Read more on mysql network security here](https://serversforhackers.com/c/mysql-network-security) if you're not familiar with creating users to connect from different hosts looks like in MySQL.

In any case, this package would need to pass the -h flag to mysqldump for that to work, e.g.:

`mysqldump -h prod-hostname -u some_user -p'some-password' [...other flags...]` ...
I haven't checked to see if the package does that already - sounds like it does!